# Setting the TabIndex property of many form controls in Visual Studio?

Tags: winforms

What is the most efficient way to set/re-order the TabIndex properties of many form controls in Visual Studio?  When I change the layout on a large form, or even on initial design, I often wonder if there's a faster way than clicking each individual control then setting the TabIndex in the properties window.

Comment: This is just another reason to RTFM :)
I won't delete this embarrassing question, just in case someone else is as ignorant as I was.

Comment: The TFM (about Tab Order) is useless not only in crowded forms (where the control may not be even visible, hidden behind the label of "taborder") but also in many simple forms with some containers.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

While in Designer mode, select Tab Order from the View menu then click on each control in the order you want. Then **remember to turn off Tab Order when you're finished**, otherwise when you select a control to do something else you lose the work you've just done (I wish Tab Order would turn off when you Save..)

Comment: That option isn't under any of the menus in VS 2010, as far as I can tell.  There *is* a Tab Order button in the "Layout" toolbar, though.

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere in VS 2012 beta neither, but I found a solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/6aa37755-2eb5-44f7-94dc-a39b9b3ee22b/ hope it helps

Comment: The visual representation also shows when there are sub-groups for tabs (such as within a group box).  I couldn't figure out why my tabbing was wrong even though I just set the individual indicies, not realizing the group box was throwing off my perceived ordering.

Comment: What if you have a hundred controls and just want to insert one near the beginning? Do you have to re-touch all of them in the correct order?

Comment: @TTT, afaik you can set it manually in Properties `TabIndex`, following controls will rearrange accordingly

Comment: Using "Tab Order" from the View menu you cannot set the **real** tab order of controls. You can only set the the tab order of containers and the tab order of the control inside its parent.

Comment: @iliasiliadis Perhaps you can share how you set the “real tab order”, and how that differs from the tab order of containers and their child controls?

Comment: By "real tab order" I mean what everyone understands. Every tab-enabled control has a "TabIndex" that clearly states if it is "before" of "after" some other. Having tenths of controls with a "TabIndex" property of 0, I assume is not helping anybody.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still don’t understand what you mean. I thought I might find out why you downvoted the answer so I could improve it, but there’s nothing here to help me.

Comment: By searching I came to this answer. Which led me to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLNI1.png), not a helpful way to set TabOrder, so down-voted.  Apart of this, TabOrder is presumed for setting the TAB keystroke order. Which means: if we have 100 controls (panels,groups,buttons etc.) and we want the TAB key to go through the 20, we cannot depend on what is the TabIndex of containers (take a look at what Brian J commented above). We just want these 20 controls to be indexed in a meaningful integer way (1,2,3,4 etc. etc. or 0,1,2,3 etc.etc.)

Comment: @stuartd you are right. Now that I faced the problematic way winforms uses tabindexing realized that there is no way to set a tab order in winforms apart from  that of "container-> control" (sorry, can't undo my down vote for the moment. just undo, not upvote).

Comment: @iliasiliadis indeed, winforms tab order is a bit clunky and unintuitive, but it's all there is!

Answer (score 11):

Bring up the Form in design mode.

Click the View Menu -> Tab Order

Then a little number will show up on each form representing its tab order.  Now click each item in order that you want their tab order set.

Answer (score 4):

To bring up the tab order in VS2012 while in Design View Click on the actual form then goto VIEW / TAB ORDER then this will enable the tab order window.

once you have finished changing the tab order go back to VIEW / TAB ORDER this will deactivate the tab order layout

Comment: The "Click on the actual form" is the part of the others answers are missing.

Answer (score -1):

In case some other will have the same issue(you may also see print screens in link):
First step: as you are in Design View of your form in menu go to View and select Tab Order. Second step: on your controls will appear a number that represents the Tab Order of your control. For re - setting tab order press a click in ascending order the controls that want to succeed, including Labels(even they are not selectable). I hope it is very intuitive this step for you too.
Print screens at: http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2013/06/how-to-set-tab-order-for-controls-in.html