# How can I set the tab order in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a bunch of buttons on a form and when the person presses <kbd>TAB</kbd> I want the focus of the controls move in a specific order. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The tool mentioned over here might prove very useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256814/271351

Comment: @cjbarth thanks!! but not 3 years later :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have form with lots of control then manage tab index by below method:

- Open form in design mode.
- Click on “View” from toolbar --> “Tab Order” at bottom.

Example:

[image]

Then just click on controls one by one in order that you want to set tab order.

Comment: thanks for this, it helped me too ;) the print screen as well

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in the Designer as well, see [Setting the TabIndex property of many form controls in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837752/setting-the-tabindex-property-of-many-form-controls-in-visual-studio/837787#837787)

Answer (score 6):

Each item in your form-designer should have a **TabIndex** property.

Set the TabIndex in ascending order. (low-to-high)

Answer (score 2):

Change the `TabIndex` property of your controls and enumerate them according to your need.