# Winform and Tab?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, ide

When setting up a Winform with textbox controls, and going to View Tab Order -

1. how do you indicate when you are done setting tab order and want it to be saved?
2. Is there any other way to set the Tab Order of the controls on the form?

Comment: You can review my answer from this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12959962/1218422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To indicate that you are done, hit **ESC**.
2. You can change the tab order by setting the TabIndex property on the controls themselves

Answer (score 1):

1. When you are finished, click the tab order again or press Esc.
2. You can set the tab order using the Tab Index property either in design mode or at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you begin setting the tab order you klick the tab order button. When you are done you click it again to disable it.
2. You can set the tab order number in each controls properties sheet or at runtime via the TabIndex value.