# How can I remove or reset the tab order in VS 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a tab order set, but have rearranged a lot of controls, added more, removed some. 
So now when I click view Tab Order it show the tab oeders by cluttering the screen with tons of numbers. Is there a way to clear these and start over?
I tried setting tabstop to false on the controls, hoping it would 'clear' their entries in the View Tab Order, but when I go back to view the tab order they still have numbers in them.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can review my answer from below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12959962/1218422

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those numbers are the order that your controls will be hit when pressing the 'Tab' key. When in View Tab Order mode, you can click on the controls in the order that you want them to be hit. That will re-order them. You'll notice that the numbers start changing as you click.

Here's the [MSDN page on how to do Tab Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

None of the provided answers really satisfied me. With the accepted one, you still have to go through each control...

Here's what I did:

- Open the [Form].Designer file.
- Quick replace with regular expressions: .TabIndex = {.+}, replace with: .TabIndex = 99 or whatever highest number you want (or even zero (0)).

[image]

- THEN go to design view and set the order via Tab Order command

Comment: very good solution, this will start the ordering from a clean slate

Comment: In VS 2017 (+?) the search expression is \.TabIndex = (.+) and replace is .TabIndex = 0 \r

Answer (score 1):

In case some other will have the same issue(you may also see print screens in link):
First step: as you are in Design View of your form in menu go to View and select Tab Order. Second step: on your controls will appear a number that represents the Tab Order of your control. For re - setting tab order press a click in ascending order the controls that want to succeed, including Labels(even they are not selectable). I hope it is very intuitive this step for you too.
Print screens at: http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2013/06/how-to-set-tab-order-for-controls-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the tools that VS provides to help with tab order to be lacking, but I found another tool that could help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256814/271351

Answer (score 0):

Use "Send to Back" and "Bring to Front" to Shuffle the order of the docked controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for **this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtTextBox1);** and check is it added to the same **groupbox**.

Answer (score 0):

I use in VS2019 :

replace : .TabIndex = .\d+
with : .TabIndex = 0