# TextBox Enter Key - Sub Panels within a main Panel

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem with this scenario (See Title). I have 6 Sub Panels within one big Panel. I have made a TextBox class that inherits from the main Textbox. I am trying to use the KeyPressed Event Handler for handling the Enter key. When a User presses the Enter Key, it moves from one TextBox inside a sub panel into the next sub panel. So far, I have gotten the Enter Key Event handler to work for the panel where the focus is without jumping to the next panel.

Below is subroutine that I am using to control the movements.
The problem is that I am unable to jump from one sub panel to another. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Protected Shared Sub NextControl(ByVal tControl As Control, ByVal Direction As Boolean)

    Dim pControl As Control = tControl.TopLevelControl
    tControl = pControl.GetNextControl(tControl, Direction)

    If Direction = False Then
        Dim tParent As Control
        While TypeOf tControl Is UserControl
            tParent = tControl.Parent
            tControl = pControl.GetNextControl(tControl, Direction)
            If tControl.Parent Is tParent Then
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End If

    If tBox_P00.ControlNesting > 0 Then
        'Dim i As Integer
        pControl = tControl.Parent
        For i As Integer = 0 To tBox_P00.ControlNesting - 2
            pControl = pControl.Parent
        Next
    End If

    If Not tControl Is Nothing Then
        Do Until (tControl.TabStop = True) AndAlso (tControl.Enabled = True) AndAlso (tControl.Visible = True) AndAlso (TypeOf tControl Is Tbx00)

            tControl = pControl.GetNextControl(tControl, Direction)

            'Last in the Panel
            If tControl Is Nothing Then

                tBox_P00.Select(0, tBox_P00.TextLength)
                Beep()
                Exit Sub

            End If
        Loop
        tControl.Focus()
    Else
        tBox_P00.Select(0, tBox_P00.TextLength)
        Beep()
    End If

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see a question.  What actually goes wrong?

Comment: The intention of the loops in that code is very unclear.  Just call GetNextControl() once and do nothing more.

Comment: Inside the sub Panel there are at least 10 other textboxes. The loop is to filter out the non-input ones to the inputs. So the loop actually looks and tries to locate the next input box.

Comment: Why do you have the TabStop property set to true on controls that shouldn't get the focus?  Fix that and GetNextControl() gets the job done.

Comment: The TapStop property helps to filter. Each of the output textboxes have tabstop set to false except the input ones. GetNextControl() seems to only work within the focus's Sub Panel - It doesn't help me shift to the next Sub Panels that contain other input fields

Comment: Then use the form's GetNextControl() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you are complicating things. As HansPassant mentioned you can use [GetNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol.aspx) to do the work for you:

This code will move the focus to the next textbox on the form ([based on tab index order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603444/how-can-i-set-the-tab-order-in-vb-net)) when enter is pressed:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
        Do
            ctl = Me.GetNextControl(ctl, True)
        Loop Until TypeOf ctl Is TextBox
        ctl.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

You could then expand this to handle all textbox KeyDown events.