# How to set textboxes in order in VB?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, key, mouseevent

I want to make textboxes and other input values in order, so I can move from one to another with "Tab" button.

At the moment I have 3 textboxes for date input and when I run the program it always set my cursor to 3rd textbox by default instead of 1st.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the TabIndex property of many form controls in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837752/setting-the-tabindex-property-of-many-form-controls-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio, you'll want to set the Tab Order.

To do this, when in the Form Designer, go to the View Menu, then select "Tab Order"

You'll get a little index on all your controls. Simply click the controls in the order you want to move through them with the Tab Key and you'll be set.  Be sure to turn off the Tab Order when you're done by going back to the View Menu and de-selecting Tab Order.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

look into `TabIndex` and also, through your menu (depending on your VS version - i'm using 2010) - use `View` > `Tab Order`